# Extract Rests From MIDI Using Music21 (or alternative) and write to seperate MIDI track

Tags: python, midi, music21

I am working on trying to parse a simple single channel, single instrument MIDI file into notes and rests.  I understand that 'rests' are not encoding into MIDI directly, rather they are simply the absence of a NoteOn/NoteOff pair.

What I am trying to do is read the data from the first (and only) MIDI channel (0) and extract notes and rests using Music21 in Python.  Once I have done this:

1. I will leave the notes on Channel 0
2. I will encode the rests as normal NoteOn/NoteOff pairs on a seperate channel, Channel 1.  I can also capture the duration of the rests here.

I can then use this data to display both the notes and rests in a front-end which I am building later.

So my questions:

1. Is Music21 appropriate for this?  Or is there a simpler way?
2. If Music21 is appropriate, what is a good strategy to do this?
3. I am currently downloading a sample MIDI file from a URL using `requests` and attempting to parse this music21 using `requests.content`.  Is this appropriate?

Thanks for your help, I am very new to the Music21 lib!

Answer (score 2):

music21 will definitely creates notes and rests from a MIDI file. What further aims do you have?

```
import music21
parsed = music21.converter.parse('source.mid')
for elem in parsed.flat.notesAndRests:
    print(elem)
    print(elem.pitch.name if elem.isNote else "REST")
    print(elem.quarterLength)
```

Comment: Good answer, but rests don't have a 'pitch'